# How to do a custom, ad hoc, affine transformation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

I have a data set of unknown origin (probably CAD) and I have determined that the correct transformation for this data into the projection that I want is as follows:

(4x + 2205432),  (30y + 1254781)

However, The "Custom Projection" tool is a bit vexing and there is no obvious way for me to enter parameters like this in.  I would call this an affine transformation but I don't see that option available.

I've never done this before, can someone tell me how it's done?

Comment: Maybe if you wrote a program and could then access the ITransformation methods. CAD layers can be georeferenced with a conformal (not affine) transformation. A conformal one only allow a single scale, not two though. What about trying the georeferencing (if CAD) or spatial adjustment toolbars?

Comment: @mkennedy I think a copy/paste of your comment would be suitable as a short answer.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @mkennedy:

> Maybe if you wrote a program and could then access the ITransformation
>   methods. CAD layers can be georeferenced with a conformal (not affine)
>   transformation. A conformal one only allow a single scale, not two
>   though.

Perhaps try the georeferencing (if CAD) or spatial adjustment toolbars.